# Cannot find the bug in my code to delete a character from a string

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void squeeze(char s[], int c);

int main(){

    int i, max = 200,c;
    char s[max];

    for(i=0; i <max-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF; ++i){
        s[i] =c;
    }
    squeeze(s, c);

    printf("%s", s);

}
void squeeze (char s[], int c){

    int i, j;
    for(i=j=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(s[i] != c){
            s[j++] = s[i];
        }   
    }
    s[j] = '\0';
}
```

The above stated code is supposed to remove all the occurrences of character c from the input string. The code is compiling without any errors and yet whilst running the code it is printing the same input string even when it contains the character c. I can't figure out where I am going wrong here.

Comment: 0) `s` isn't NUL(`'\0'`) terminate. 1) at `squeeze` `s` isn't include `c(EOF)`

Comment: What are you trying to do with the call `squeeze(s, c);`? What character do you want to remove from the string?

Comment: @interjay I am trying to delete character c from the string using squeeze(s,c)

Comment: And what specific character do you think that would be? Do you think that it would delete the letter "c"? If so, you really should go back to the basics and learn what a variable is.

Comment: Not unless you answer my question about what character you want to remove. It seems like you are barely familiar with the C language and just pieced together some code you found somewhere. I suggest reading a good book and learning the language.

Comment: I want to remove character 'c'. And yes, you're right, I am barely familiar with C language I am studying from the k&r book. And No, I did not pieced together anything, I wrote this code based on my understanding of the concepts so far. And now, as I look at all these comments (including yours) I realise it is pretty much flawed. I will go through the concepts again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never terminate `s` before calling `squeeze()`, so it's not a valid string. This code thus has undefined behavior.

Then this:

```
squeeze(s, c);
```

should probably be

```
squeeze(s, 'c');
```

if you want to remove the character `'c'`. Now you're passing the variable `c`, whose value there is `EOF`; it makes no sense.

Comment: Additionally, it's being called with `c==EOF`, which is pointless.

Comment: shouldnt it terminate when I call EOF?

Comment: @diplodocus , Add `s[i]='\0';` just after the loop in `main`

Comment: @diplodocus , The loop ends when `c` is `EOF`(Assuming `i` is less than 199). The string `s` will not contain `EOF`

Comment: @CoolGuy why do i need s[i] = '\0'?

Comment: @diplodocus `'\0'` is C's string terminator, it has to be after the last valid character of the string, to mark the end. That's what your loop in `squeeze()` looks for!

Comment: @CoolGuy you're right it wont, but I call EOF on my own manually, shouldnt it work then?

Comment: @diplodocus . "*but I call EOF on my own manually*" and this is assigned it `c`. Now calling `squeeze` with the second parameter `c`(`EOF`) doesn't make sense as `s` won't contain it.

Comment: I added s[i] = '\0' after the loop to mark the end of the string and still the behavior is same. No difference. Still printing the same input string.

Comment: @diplodocus Of course, since you're trying to squeeze out `EOF`, a character which is not in `s` to begin with (and which is, in fact, not a valid `char`-type value at all). You're passing the wrong value as the second argument to `squeeze()`. Don't you read the comments? Perhaps you meant to pass `'c'`, the character 'c'.

Comment: Apologise to all for the mass confusion, i meant character 'c' all along. It all makes much sense now. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

main change like as

```
...
printf("Input string : ");
fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
printf("Enter you want to delete characters : ");
c = getchar();

squeeze(s, c);
...
```

Comment: Note: `fgets` includes the newline character in `s`

Comment: @CoolGuy It does not matter that contains newline. The original code do not eliminate of newline. also call `squeeze(s, '\n');`

Comment: I know. Just a note for the OP and future viewers.

Comment: In the sense that reverse to allow the input of multiple newline, my code they've been degraded.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your were trying to removed all occurrences of the last character read in `squeeze`, among other things, it was failing because you were passing the `null-terminator` `s[i]` as `c` to `squeeze`. That would never work. A few revisions and it now removes all occurrences of the last char read:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void squeeze(char *s, int c);

int main(){

    int i = 0, max = 200, c = 0;
    char s[max];

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < max-1)
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = 0;

    if (i > 0)
        squeeze (s, s[i-1]);

    printf("\n  %s\n\n", s);

    return 0;
}

void squeeze (char *s, int c) {

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (s[i]) {
        if(s[i] != c){
            s[j++] = s[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    s[j] = 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/squeeze <<< "this_is_first_z_and_last_z"

  this_is_first__and_last_
```

Comment: `i < max`  has been deteriorated. `s[i-1]` needs guard like as `i > 0`.

Comment: Now I really feel dumb... The check on `max` needed to be on `max - 1`, but beyond that, I'm not following what you mean by "`i < max` has been deteriorated"?

Comment: You have purposely change it from `i < max - 1` to `i < max`.

Comment: Ohhh.. I could have looked that this for hours and not snapped to that fact. (getting old is a bitch)